# Using a JOIN to display Username from ID

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I am trying to use a JOIN to connect the "user_id" from my "users" table, with my "topic_by" in my "topics" table, I searched around and set up the following code.

```
$sql = "SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_date, topics.topic_cat, topics.topic_by
            FROM topics 
            INNER JOIN users ON topics.topic_by=users.user_id
            WHERE topics.topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . " ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC;";
```

It's not returning any errors, but when I try to call the user_name..

. $row['users.user_name'] .

There is just a blank space where the data should be, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't select the `user_name` column in your `SELECT` statement.

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_date, topics.topic_cat, topics.topic_by, users.user_name
  FROM topics 
  INNER JOIN users ON topics.topic_by=users.user_id
  WHERE topics.topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . " ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC;";
```

To select this column data in your `$row` array, you would write it like: `$row['user_name']`. The keys in your `$row` array are the column names (or aliases, if provided) but do not include the table name.

Comment: Thanks, just tried still no output, is this part correct
. $row['users.user_name'] .
?

Comment: @user2542256 - Using the query above, all you would need to put is `$row['user_name']`.